# Mainstream for desktop web apps: Adobe Air vs Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: adobe, air, appcelerator

We are developing HTML5/CSS/JS web app and intended to run it on Win MAC and Linux desktops.

Which environment should we choose in terms of future investment protection - Adobe Air, Appcelerator Titanium or probably another one?

We prefer Titanium, but it seems stuck in development - no updates since spring 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I love Titanium!

If you look at the features / issues / bug list for 1.5 you will see that they are really working their butts off on items. Primarily in the mobile space. I think their cause is pretty huge and they will be very  successful.  We are sticking it out with them for sure.  Plus they just announced this week 9 million in VC.

That should allow them to hire some more development power.

I've never really been an Adobe fan. Photoshop, PDF; rest i could now live without.